# Custom mysql query for pulling in best answer

Tags: php, mysql

I created a custom forum using PHP and MySQL. I have two tables, one for threads, and one for the messages in the threads.

I am implementing a feature where an admin can select a message as the best answer. In the messages table, there is a BOOL column for best_answer.

On the page that lists the threads, I want to indicate whether the thread has a best answer selected.

Is it possible to write a query that will select all threads but also look at the messages for the thread and see if a best answer has been selected?

I was trying something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `threads`
JOIN `messages` ON `threads`.`id` = `messages`.`thread_id`
WHERE `messages`.`best_answer` = 1
```

However, that only pulls threads with a best answer, I still need it to pull all threads and have a column so I can check if it has a best answer or not.

Would it be better to just add a column to the threads table to mark if it has a best answer selected or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `threads`
LEFT JOIN `messages` ON `threads`.`id` = `messages`.`thread_id` AND `messages`.`best_answer` = 1
GROUP BY `threads`.`id`
```

this gives you all threads and the best answer if possible.
`LEFT JOIN` is used to also display the threads where no best answer is found
You can use every expression in the `ON`clause that evualates to true or false.

The `GROUP BY` is used to only give you one entry within the resultset with a specific `thread_id` and thus only one best answer.

You should, however, move the "best answer" section out of the `messages` table into a into the `threads` table. As one Thread can only have one best answer and not the other way round.

Comment: The interface only allows one best answer per thread, but that is a good point about moving it out of the messages table and into the threads table.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a pure SQL solution, then this should work for you.

```
select * 
from threads
join (
    select threads.id, 
    sum(messages.best_answer) as has_best_answer
    from threads join messages
    on threads.id = messages.thread_id
    group by threads.id
)temp
on threads.id = temp.id
```

Edit : Shortened the query to

```
select * 
from threads
join (
    select thread_id, 
    sum(messages.best_answer) as has_best_answer
    from messages
    group by thread_id
)temp
on threads.id = temp.thread_id
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding nonaggregated columns not listed in the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you. I initially thought about doing a self join, and then realized it was a bad solution, so I switched to the subquery instead.

Comment: I dont understand the necessity for the subselect. If he just does a `left join`  and adds `best_answer` check to the `ON` clause, he gets a `null` value for threads that don't have a best answer selected, the  result set of the subselect however must be built before the `JOIN` and should therefore use a lot more memory, from what i understand? Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, you can "shorten" this query be getting rid of the extra join in the subquery.

Answer (score 4):

On occasion, it is easier to "see" the result by using a subquery in the `select` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (select MAX(bestanswer) from messages m where m.thread_id = t.id
       ) as HasBestAnswer
from threads t
```

This restricts the results only to threads, though, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: And I thought I got the shortest possible query for the question. +1

Comment: This works, as does nihundle's answer. I slightly modified both. Is it better to use a subquery or a join?

Answer (score 0):

This should pull the data as you are trying to:

```
SELECT threads.*, messages.best_answer
FROM threads
LEFT JOIN messages ON threads.id = messages.thread_id
GROUP BY threads.id
ORDER BY messages.best_answer DESC
```

And later, with the result set...

```
while ( $row = [...] ){
    if ( $row['best_answer'] > 0 ) { 
        // Best Answer is set, do something
    } else {
        // No best answer, do something else
    }
}
```

We do not include the `WHERE` clause, which was limiting your results to just those `threads` with a `message` whose `best_answer` column is set to 1. Now, we get all `threads`, and we can check in the loop whether a `best_answer` is 1 or 0.

Comment: I think you'll want to put `messages.best_answer` in an aggregate function... like `max(messages.best_answer)`... otherwise you might just get the `best_answer` for a random message in the thread.